# CQ5 - search - Enabling synonym matching

Tags: aem

Any help with following and rather straightforward functionality is much appreciated. I'm trying to enable synonym matching in CQ5 | AEM and I've been using http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/developing/searching_in_crx.html as a guideline.

I'm trying to create a synonym and to have a search working as well for "tablet" as for "tableau" and "Tablette". I created a small synonyms.properties file with following entries:

```
tablet=Tablette
tablet=tableau
Tablette=tablet
```

(Third line is rather obligatory since being the counterpart of the first line). I adapted worspace.xml and repository.xml as well:

synonyms.properties is located in 
C:\temp\author\crx-quickstart\repository\workspaces\crx.default\index

worspace.xml is located in 
C:\temp\author\crx-quickstart\repository\workspaces\crx.default

following entries have been added

```
<SearchIndex class="com.day.crx.query.lucene.LuceneHandler">
    <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
    <param name="resultFetchSize" value="50"/>
    <param name="synonymProviderClass" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.PropertiesSynonymProvider"/>
    <param name="synonymProviderConfigPath" value="synonyms.properties"/>
</SearchIndex>
```

repository.xml is located in 
C:\temp\author\crx-quickstart\repository
following entries have been added

```
<SearchIndex class="com.day.crx.query.lucene.LuceneHandler">
    <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
    <param name="resultFetchSize" value="50"/>
    <param name="synonymProviderClass" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.PropertiesSynonymProvider"/>
    <param name="synonymProviderConfigPath" value="synonyms.properties"/>
</SearchIndex>
```

When I search on tablets I get my tablets and when I search on tableau I get the corresponding entries as well but for sure the 2 keywords are not treated as a synonym.

Can someone please confirm the correctness of the configuration and whether it's possible to add additional debugging?

Many thanks,
Wim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this enigma by searching on Jackrabbit (since AEM uses Apache Jackrabbit query). The trick is to use the tilde or the ~ character.

Assuming you use JCR-SQL2,  simply use following syntax:

```
SELECT productType FROM [nt:base] AS s WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE([/content/mywebsite/en/products]) 
and contains(productType, '~tableau')
```

I hope other users will benefit from this info. 
Wim